# How to add RASP security feature to Flutter v1 android app

Tags: flutter, security, flutter-dependencies

I'm working on flutter version 1 android app. I need to add RASP security to my app. Are there any packages available for this?

Answer (score 3):

check out freerasp package in pub.dev.

[FreeRASP](https://pub.dev/packages/freerasp)

Comment: It's not working on flutter version 1

Comment: Just curious, why don't you consider upgrading flutter?